# cache method call results in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to cache method call results in es6, and how it can be done correct?

example es2015:

```
Helper.prototype.getCount = function (requestURL) {
    var cache = Helper.prototype.getCounters.cache,
        result = '';

    if (cache[requestURL] === undefined) {
        result = doSomething();
    } else {
        // if result wild in cache -> load it
        result = cache[requestURL];
    }

    return result;

    function doSomething() {
        var result = 1; // ... some havy operations

        // save results in cache
        cache[requestURL] = result;

        return result;
    }
}

Helper.prototype.getCounters.cache = {};
```

I'm looking for something like this, but in es6.

```
class Helper {
    getCount(url) {
       //...
    } 
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: If it works in ES5, it's also valid ES6. What's the issue with ES6?

Comment: This is already ES6. You can do in ES6 everything you could do in ES5. `Helper.prototype.getCounters.cache` is absolute nonsense and should be never used. This will result in having same cache for all instances, but looks more obscure than `Helper.cache`, and it's very likely like a dev didn't expect it to work this way.

Comment: if u r trying to cache a requestedURL, then fetch() API in es6 might have a cache-ing option.

Comment: u can try some like : `fetch("<whateverRequestUrl>", {cache: "force-cache"})
    .then(function(response) { /* consume the response */ });`

Comment: @estus So is a static `cache` property that is shared by all instances better placed on the constructor `Helper.cache` instead of the prototype `Helper.prototype.cache`?

Comment: @le_m Yes, if this is the intention. If cache is unique for each instance, it should be `this.cache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching return values to avoid unwanted intensive operations is a great idea. The most common scenario for caching in OOP is when you need to create a lot of similar objects from a factory class. This is actually a GoF pattern (see **Flyweight**).

In your case, if I understand your problem well, you are trying to use caching to avoid useless AJAX calls. With ES6, I think a good implementation could involve `Map` for caching and `Promise` for better asynchronous handling. In the following implementation with the GitHub API, `ajax` is a static method, `getUser` is a prototype property and `cache` is a static attribute.

```js
class GitHub {
  static ajax(username) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (this.status === 200) {
            let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText),
                user = {
                  name: json.name,
                  bio: json.bio
                };
            GitHub.cache.set(username, user);
            resolve(user);
          } else {
            reject(new Error(`${this.status} ${this.statusText}`));
          }
        }
      };

      req.open('GET', `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`, true);
      req.send(null);
    });
  }
  
  getUser(username = 'Badacadabra') {
    if (!GitHub.cache.has(username)) {
      console.log('AJAX');
      return GitHub.ajax(username);
    } else {
      console.log('Cache');
      return GitHub.cache.get(username);
    }
  }
}
GitHub.cache = new Map();

let github = new GitHub();

github.getUser()
  .then(console.log)
  .then(() => github.getUser())
  .then(console.log)
  .then(() => github.getUser())
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```